# Webpack: bundle multiple vendor css in one separate file?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I want to bundle several standard libraries into two files bundle.js and bundle.css with webpack 3.8

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'vendor': [
      'jquery',
      'popper.js',
      'bootstrap',
    ],

  },

    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
              rules:[
                    {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                      fallback: "style-loader",
                      use: "css-loader"
                    })
                  }
                ],


  },

  plugins: [

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: true 
      }
    }),

    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),

  ]
};
```

After running webpack, I get only bundle.js file:

```
    Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  264 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
```

How should I config webpack to produce bundle.css ?

Comment: can you share your vendor files. Files which are included in your vendor. I think you have not imported any .css file inside the above.

Comment: @Pravesh Khatri Maybe :), I failed to find any example on my case, so I simply install all packages with npm in standard folders like /home/user_folder/projects/project_folder/node_modules/bootstrap. Do I need to import css files for each vendor package separately ?

Comment: if you have import any .css file in your files provided in above entry. Then it will automatically create a bundle with help of loader you have provided. Other wise to include it you to specify in your entry point.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this right now. Do I understand this correctly: webpack can find the necessary js files automatically, but not the css files?

Comment: I think they find any kind of files as we provide their respective loaders. As, loaders are responsible for finding files which are imported in the files which you have provided in entry point

Comment: If you want to add css files externally. I can post it in answer as well.

Comment: @Pravesh Khatri I created a file, added it as an entry `entry: { 'vendor': './entry.js',}`,and imported all js an css like `require('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');` inside that file. And it worked :) If you add it as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

**First**

You can import your `.css` files in the files provided at entry point.

for eg.

if `entry: index.js`

in `index.js` you have to import your css files

```
import './*.css'      // all css files in root
```

**Second**

you can provide it in your entry point.

```
entry: {
   {
    'vendor': [
      'jquery',
      'popper.js',
      'bootstrap',
    ],
    'styles': '/*.css'    
  }
}
```